# Unresolved inclusion/objects when building native-audio example?

Tags: audio, android-ndk

I just installed the latest android SDK and NDK. I want to get familiar with OpenSL so I started with the `native-audio` example project in `ndk/samples` and I'm having trouble with `native-audio-jni.c` file. Eclipse cannot resolve any of the include files and doesn't recognize any of the OpenSL definitions. Doesn't even know what `NULL` means. I can build the project but once I open the `.c` file (once the file runs through the parser) the project won't build any more.
Other people have had the same problems and many solutions exist but none of them works for the latest SDK.

How can I fix all these errors?

Comment: I have this same issue and am curious as well.

Comment: Hmm, deleting and recreating the project seems to have fixed most of the issues. Some symbols still do give issues so it's not 100%.

Comment: And it broke again. :( It seems to not like linked folders...